# How to display a data table with R plumber

Tags: r, datatable, plumber

I´ve got a data frame that I would like to make accessible via R plumber.

I am using knitr do to this.

```
#* html table
#* @serializer html
#* @get /test
function() {
  data <- iris
  knitr::kable(data, "html")
}
```

Now I would like to add filter/sorting options and maybe color every 2nd row light gray. I though about using datatable from the DT package. I use this in shiny a lot. My attempts at using the package failed.

- DT::renderDataTable(dt) leads to "...meant to be used when embedding snippets of Shiny code..."
- Just trying datatable(iris) leads to "Not compatible with requested type: [type=list; target=raw]"

With ChatGPT I wrote some simple datatable html which works, but I am guessing there is a way to use an existing package to do this in a much simpler way..? Thank you!

```
my_DT <- function(table){
  html_response <- paste0(
    "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>",
    "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" ",
    "href=\"https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css\">",
    "<script src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js\"></script>",
    "<script src=\"https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js\"></script>",
    "</head><body>",
    table,
    "<script>$(document).ready(function(){$('table').DataTable();});</script>",
    "</body></html>"
  )
  html_response
}

#* data table test
#* @serializer html
#* @get /test
function() {
    data <- iris

    # dt <- DT::datatable(data, options = list(pageLength = 5, autoWidth = TRUE))
    my_DT(data)
}
```

Comment: `plumber`  has nothing to do with "showing" anything, its intent is to support _programmatic_ access, whether to retrieve data or do something else. In your first case, this still works fine since you are returning html. The datatable javascript library, on the other hand, uses javascript to provide interactive table components (sorting, etc), and is not something that can be as-easily returned like this. If you want to "show" something (e.g., using the `DT` package) then I suggest you should be using `shiny` instead of `plumber`.

Comment: That is true. I thought modifying plumber would be the easier way instead of deploying a shiny app just to be able to filter a table...

Comment: Further, the way that `plumber` APIs are made available in an interactive fashion is actually an OpenAPI thing, where the default plumber API uses Swagger. Other methods exist, I'm not a pro in any of them. But if you want to address how the user interacts with the interactive plumber interface, look to the openapi enabler. (Beyond this I am not proficient enough to really help much ... but I really think that expecting datatable javascript stuff to work from a plumber endpoint is asking too much, perhaps unreachable.)